# Can't install Apple Fitness app to iPad 14.3

Tags: ipad, fitness+, apple-one

I just updated my iPad Pro 2020 to iPadOS 14.3.  I'm also an Apple One Premier member.

When I try to download the Apple Fitness app to my iPad, the App Store doesn't let me.  I get an error message: "This app requires specific features not available on this device."

Apple's [announcement](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2020/12/apple-fitness-plus-the-next-era-of-fitness-is-here-and-everyones-invited/) states

> For usage with iPad, Fitness+ requires iPad Pro, iPad (5th generation or later), iPad mini 4 or later, iPad Air 2, or iPad Air (3rd generation or later), running iOS 14.3.

It looks like there might be a problem for iPad users right now.  I can get it to work on my iPhone so I know it's available.  Is there a way to download this to an iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking like there is a delay in rolling it out to iPadOS devices at the moment.

I'm sure they will get this issue resolved shortly.

> https://www.macrumors.com/2020/12/14/apple-fitness-plus-ipad-unavailable/

Added a link with new about the issue.

Comment: Yep, this was it. After waiting 5 hours, the app finally could be downloaded. Thanks!

Comment: Took at restart of my iPad to get it to download, but working for me too.